# What is the difference between creating a class object using the new command and not?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to learn classes by making a simple board game in C++. I have a class named "board" that has two functions, drawBoard and fillBoard. 
When I'm creating the object in my main function, I seem to have two options.

1) board gameBoard;

2) board* gameboard = new board();

What is the difference between these two? Do I always have to create a pointer when using the 'new' operator? I'm mostly trying to understand what situations I would use one over the other in.

Also, when I define it as a pointer, do I always have to use the "->" instead of the dot when calling functions?

board.drawBoard(); versus board->drawBoard();

What is different between these two?

Comment: I would highly suggest google.com and cplusplus.com

Comment: Google for c++ and dynamic memory

Comment: Possible duplicate: [RAII and smart pointers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c/395158#395158)

Comment: you might start reading [proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599308/proper-stack-and-heap-usage-in-c/599327#599327)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673998/what-is-difference-between-instantiating-an-object-using-new-vs-without

Comment: rereading your question, i'd also recommend [what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome) for the second part

Answer (score 0):

> 1) board gameBoard;

This one is created on stack

> 2) board* gameboard = new board();

This one is created on heap.

> Do I always have to create a pointer when using the 'new'

Yes.

> do I always have to use the "->" instead of the dot when calling functions

-> operator is just a shortcut to (*board).drawBoard().
pointer are variables holding address of other variables if you want to access the variable that the pointer points to you use the star. The parenthesis are because of operator precedance

Comment: And you're expecting OP to know what the stack and the heap are?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You pointed me in the right direction to understand what is actually going on in the background. I read about the stack and heap and now have an unrelated question: since you're constantly freeing up memory in the heap does it get very fragmented? Would fragmentation even slow RAM down the way it does with a hard drive? If it does, is there something that periodically defragments the heap?

Comment: read this: http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592804/how-do-i-workaround-heap-fragmentation-in-a-c-server-program

Comment: Not correct.  The `board gameBoard;` depends on where it is defined.  When outside of a function, it will be in automatic or global storage, which is usually not on the stack.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews *automatic* is only when it is inside a function. Outside a function is *static* storage.